# How can I remove hardcoded numbers from this TikZ algorithm for drawing a circle of circles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I have some TikZ code for drawing a circle of little circle images (for showing pictures of a team of people). The number of people shown can vary, so I'm trying to remove hardcoded numbers to make it easier to change the code for different numbers of people.

I have made an initial attempt at this by defining the variables `numberOfMembers` and `startAngle`. The variable `numberOfMembers` is used in a calculation to divide up a circle.

How could I reduce the hardcoding in this code?

For example, how could I make a list of images, rather than listing each image with an index (in this example, up to image 8)? How could the division operation be made to produce a real number output?

---

```
\documentclass[american, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{CERNBlue1}{RGB}{0, 83, 161}

\def\basiceval#1{\the\numexpr#1\relax}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\imagesDirectory}{images}
\def\numberOfMembers{8}
\def\startAngle{30}

\tikzset{%
    image 1/.initial=\imagesDirectory/AK.png,
    image 2/.initial=\imagesDirectory/SB.png,
    image 3/.initial=\imagesDirectory/WBM.png,
    image 4/.initial=\imagesDirectory/MP.png,
    image 5/.initial=\imagesDirectory/SN.png,
    image 6/.initial=\imagesDirectory/RETT.png,
    image 7/.initial=\imagesDirectory/GA.png,
    image 8/.initial=\imagesDirectory/JR.png,
    path image/.style={path picture={%
        \edef\imageFile{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/image #1}}%
        \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
            \includegraphics[height=1 cm]{\imageFile}
        };
    }}
}

\begin{center}
\resizebox{10 cm}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\numberOfMembers}
    \draw [
        path image=\i,
        color=CERNBlue1
    ](
        \i * \basiceval{360/\numberOfMembers} + \startAngle:1.5
    )
    circle [radius=0.5 cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please try and convert your MWE to a compilable one (we do not have your pictures, but they could be substituted by any other image/tikz).

Comment: @zeroth Thanks for the suggestion. My specific example uses image files by necessity, so I'd have to upload image files somewhere and then suggest people download them, which I don't think is reasonable. I think it's fairly clear that the images can be substituted for any handy image.

Comment: You can quite easily substitute the images with other things (for testing), whom would you rather help, a) the math student who did read the homework, b) the math student who just showed up. This isn't about clarity of the question, rather it is to help those who can answer your question. As it is, an answer has to make up their own example to actually test that it works. I would not consider that burden reasonable. :)

Comment: You could use characters from the phaistos or simpsons packages.

Comment: @zeroth Add `[demo]` option to graphicx package.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way that you can further modify

```
\documentclass[american, a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %<-- use demo to hide errors
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Sample image name array
\def\imagenamearray{{"example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image","example-image-c",
    "example-image-16x10","example-image-10x16","example-image-golden","example-image-16x9"}}

\tikzset{%
    team necklace start angle/.initial=0,
    team necklace start angle=0,
    team necklace options/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0.5cm},
    team necklace draw/.code={%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberOfMembers{dim(#1)-1}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\teamnecklaceanglestep{(360/\numberOfMembers)}%
        \foreach\x in{0,...,\numberOfMembers}{%
            \node[team necklace options,path picture={%
                \node at (path picture bounding box.center){%
                    \pgfmathparse{#1[\x]}%
                    \includegraphics[height=1 cm]{\pgfmathresult}%
                };%
            }] at (\x*\teamnecklaceanglestep+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/team necklace start angle}:2cm) {};
        }
    }
}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[team necklace start angle=30,team necklace draw=\imagenamearray];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should replace `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberOfMembers{dim(#1)}%` with `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberOfMembers{dim(#1)-1}%`.

Comment: I was not aware of the existence of the `dim` function. And I can't find it in the documentation. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There was a time that I was reading source code. Fixed the code thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do this rather complex. As I assume that you have to give each filename anyway, I would include them in the for each with a second variable.

Here's the shrinked compilable MWE with an example image as you should have used one (for future posts :)

**Update:** now you only have to pass the list of filenames to the foreach

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,tikz}
\definecolor{CERNBlue1}{RGB}{0, 83, 161}

\def\basiceval#1{\the\numexpr#1\relax}
\def\numberOfMembers{4}
\def\startAngle{30}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \v [count=\i from 0] in {
    example-image-a,
    example-image-b,
    example-image-a,
    example-image-b}
    \draw [
        path picture={                
        \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
            \includegraphics[height=1 cm]{\v}
        };}
        color=CERNBlue1
    ](
        \i * \basiceval{360/\numberOfMembers} + \startAngle:1.5
    )
    circle [radius=0.5 cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is still hard coded that the OP is trying to avoid. Also images are from mwe package not graphics.